# WEB-INF/folder/.jsp gives 404

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a spring MVC project and bunch of jsp files. When I try to access my jsp files in WEB-INF/views/ it gives me 404.

Screenshot for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access jsp page inside `WEB-INF` folder directly. To access it you will need to create `InternalResourceViewResolver` bean for resolving path for your jsp pages:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }
```

And in your controller just return name of that jsp page:

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add/employee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addEmployee(Model model) {
        return "addEmployee";
    }
}
```

Now hit URL: http://localhost:8181/SpringMVC_CRUD/add/employee

Answer (score 2):

The stuff in `WEB-INF` is not exposed to the public URL space. You can only include/access it from other files. This is useful for templates and such (and of course, your compiled code also resides in there).

Move your public JSP outside of `WEB-INF`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is route need prefix `/`,

error 404:

```
@Result(name = "test", location="result.jsp")
```

works no error:

```
@Result(name = "test", location="/result.jsp")
```